# Are External Data Sources Read-Only?

Tags: lightning-connect

I've been able to connect Salesforce to an [External Data Source](http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/), but it appears I can only read external data. Is it possible to connect Salesforce using the External Data Source feature with full read and write capabilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, yes, they are read only (see the [release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/api_cti/release-notes/rn_mobile_salesforce1_newfeat_platform_connect.htm)). Salesforce has said that the plan is to eventually make them writable (safe harbor applies, etc), but they are read only for now

Comment: It is a coincidence the release notes are no longer available and this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105049/are-external-objects-only-available-via-lightening-connect-now? :)

Comment: Is there a way to make to writeable using custom Adapter?

Comment: Just found out that new CRUD options are provided in DSN which allwos creating and editing of record.

Answer (score 0):

Since Winter 16, External Objects are writeable.
Refer to [these release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_external_data_writeable_objects.htm)